# Cannot read property of number

Tags: reactjs

How can I `print` in `setTimeout` with this `{newOrder.number}`?
I get this error: `Cannot read property of number`

I know this is an beginner mistake, but i dont know how to handle it.

This is my code:

```
const styles = useStyles();
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { order } = state;
  const { loading, error, newOrder } = state.orderCreate;

  const print = usePrinter("192.168.1.254", "8008");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (order.orderItems.length > 0) {
      createOrder(dispatch, order);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(newOrder.number);
    }, 2000);
    }
  }, [order]);

setTimeout(() => {
        print(newOrder.number);
    }, 2000);

return (
    <Box className={[styles.root, styles.navy]}>
      <Box className={[styles.main, styles.center]}>
        <Box>
          {loading ? (
            <CircularProgress></CircularProgress>
          ) : error ? (
            <Alert severity="error">{error}</Alert>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Typography>
                Your order number is {newOrder.number}
              </Typography>
            </>
          )}
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: `newOrder ` is null, from where are you getting `newOrder `

Comment: Also, unless you've overloaded the function (which you should not do), I don't think you actually want to be using print here. (Print opens up the print webpage dialog.) The default way to log is `console.log(yourStuff)`.

Comment: @Amruth the newOrder .number in the return is giving me a result. I only dont know how to use it in my print or console.log variable.

Comment: you can check console.log(newOrder.number). or console.log(newOrder?.number) with conditional null check

Comment: @Amruth then I get this: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined and this is the reason why i posted this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: pls post complete code

Comment: @Amruth updatet the question, this is the full code.

Comment: why do you require timeout ? data is coming from store so you can't predict the time. remove timeout

Comment: @Amruth I am getting the same error.

Comment: replace all `newOrder.number` with `newOrder?.number`